# Regex to find numbers but not if it is part of a decimal number

Tags: regex

I've the following regex

```
\b(?:\d[ -]*?){5,10}\b
```

that works but it is also returning numbers that is part of a decimal. The correct responses are shown below but at the moment it is returning **all** of them. It sees the '.' as a word boundary.

```
12.123456 = no match

Hello John 124567 = match

12345667 = match
```

Comment: `\b(?<!\.)(?:\d[ -]*){5,10}\b` should work if lookbehind is supported

Comment: Yep this worked, thanks. Can you answer the question and I'll give it a big tick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a negative lookbehind assertion in your regex:

```
\b(?<!\.)(?:\d[ -]*){5,10}\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SxJzU9/1)

`(?<!\.)` is negative lookbehind assertion that fails the match if `dot` is immediately before first digit.

Answer (score 0):

Use a blanked statement to skip and fail decimals, which causes the match of your
regex. You don't need to pick your regex apart each change you want to make.

`(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)|\.\d+)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\b(?:\d[ -]*?){5,10}\b`

https://regex101.com/r/mP0rxZ/1

Expanded

```
    (?:
         \d+ 
         (?: \. \d* )
      |  \. \d+ 
    )
    (*SKIP) (*FAIL) 
 |  
    \b 
    (?: \d [ -]*? ){5,10}
    \b
```